# Disable urlencode in POST request in Guzzle

Tags: guzzle

I am trying to post some data and Guzzle automatically urlencode() all post values. I want to disable it because its acting weird (There is a problem with the Enter character). I searched the documentation and found a reference about this

```
$query->useUrlEncoding(false);
```

but its about GET requests.

Also documentation says : "URL encoding can be disabled by passing false, enabled by passing true, set to use RFC 1738 by passing Query::FORM_URLENCODED (internally uses PHP's urlencode function), or set to RFC 3986 by passing Query::RFC_3986 (this is the default and internally uses PHP's rawurlencode function)."

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those looking, Guzzle has been completely rewritten & the docs are not yet 100%

The method is now on the Query object, and can be set like:

$request->getQuery()->setEncodingType(false);

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$request->getQuery()->useUrlEncoding(false);
```

Check out their API Doc for more info http://api.guzzlephp.org/class-Guzzle.Http.QueryString.html