# How to make Guzzle avoid encoding form_params

Tags: php, guzzle

I am using this code:

```
    $res = $client->request('POST', $this->host, [
        'auth' => [$customer_key, $customer_secret],
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'scope' => 'scope_one+scope_two',
        ],
    ]);
```

the issue is that the scope param is encoded like `scope_one%2Bscope_two` but the server is requesting it like `scope_one+scope_two`. How can I solve this?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003118/disable-urlencode-in-post-request-in-guzzle

Comment: @AnatoliyR the answer seems to use an old Guzzle version